# Can I Share Host Applications From Skype For Business Web App In A VM?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, skype-for-business

I am using Ubuntu for development but I can't share my screen in meetings because Skype For Business doesn't support Linux.
Even the "web app" doesn't work on Linux because it requires a native binary plugin.

If I run Windows in a VM I can start the Skype For Business web app and share a screen.

However, this will be the screen of the VM.

Is there any way to share the applications from my Ubuntu host with Skype for business?

Comment: Have you tried Wine? https://askubuntu.com/questions/359023/how-to-run-windows-skype-on-ubuntu-using-wine

Comment: This is Skype For Business (previously Lync) and doesn't work with Wine https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=18951

Comment: I looked around and you're not alone. I didn't fine any sane solution, but I am wondering how bad it would be if you run Windows VM on Linux and connected remote desktop from within the VM to the hosting OS. There is chance that the Skype for Business will be able to grab the remote desktop and share it. Super gross though.

Comment: I'm thinking something like that too. Right now I am trying to forward X11 from the Host to the Guest and use XMing.

Comment: Nice, that should definitely work. I had similar setup where XMing was able to render individuals windows and whole Unity UI.